# Writing a custom NAnt task able to use filters

Tags: nant

I'm trying to write a custom NAnt task that does some file-based operations.  One of the things that would be incredibly useful would be the ability to run the `<expandproperties>`  filter on one of the input files.

In the interest of keeping the task suitably generic, I simply want to enable support for the `<filterchain>` element (similar to how the `<copy>` task works).

I've been using the source for the `<copy>` task to guide me, however I keep on running into methods that are internal when it comes to writing the tasks.  I know I can use reflection to break encapsulation, but I'm reluctant to do this.

Does anyone know of any useful articles, or have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started going down the road of creating a private Filter subclass that took a TextReader (basically re-creating the PhysicalTextReader inside the NAnt source).  However I realised that, actually, there was a much easier way of reading a file through a filter chain:

```cs
[TaskName("mytask")]
public class MyTask : Task
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Chain of filters used to alter the input file's content as it is read.
    /// </summary>
    [BuildElement("filterchain")]
    public FilterChain Filters { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The input file.
    /// </summary>
    [TaskAttribute("input")]
    public FileInfo InputFile { get; set; }

    protected override void ExecuteTask()
    {
        Log(FileUtils.ReadFile(InputFile.FullName, Filters, null));
    }
}
```

Then you can use this exactly as you would expect:

```xml
<mytask input="foo.txt">
    <filterchain>
        <expandproperties />
    </filterchain>
</mytask>
```